# Convert mediawiki to word documents

Tags: mediawiki, confluence

I am trying to move a mediawiki site to confluence v5. Confluence now no longer support using the Universal Wiki Converter (UWC) for version 5. Confluence has advised that they accept "page and page tree imports in the form of Word Documents" or "Confluence Space Exports and Confluence Site Exports".

Therefore I need a way on converting the mediawiki pages into word documents, as well as retaining the structure.

Currently, I have used mediawiki's `dumpBackup.php`to create an XML dump of my wiki. I then used a [mediawikiXML_exporter.php](https://wiki.afm.co/download/attachments/23108751/mediawikiXML_exporter.php?version=2&modificationDate=1398709393121&api=v2). This created a `exported_mediawiki_pages/`directory containing all `Pages`, `File`, `Categories`, `Projects`, and `Users`. I checked and all my pages and these files contained mediawiki versions of all my pages and users etc, but stored as `.txt` files.

Given I cannot use UWC to upload this to confluence, is there a way to convert to a docx format so that I can upload into confluence?

P.S. I'm well aware I may be doing with the wrong approach so if there is a better way to do this from scratch, I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Collection to convert it to a PDF document, and then see if you can maybe convert that to word.

Comment: Sadly, that won't keep the structure of the wiki